# Manually inserting data in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am creating an app using Angular.js and Firebase and until I have the interface in working order, I am planning on manually inserting data. While it's easy enough to add key:value pairs, I haven't been able to figure out how to structure multiple levels of data, like adding an object which has multiple entries inside of it. If I import a json file, it does this, but I do not want to have to edit a json file and upload it everytime I want to make a change. Is there a way to do this that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 45):

If you head to Firebase Forge (at `https://[your-firebase].firebaseio.com`), you can load up the Graphical Debugger for your Firebase and manually add, modify, or remove data, as well as watch it as it changes in real-time.

To add hierarchical data using Forge, using the `+` button to create a new child attribute, give it a name and leave the value blank, and then use the `+` button on the child to begin adding more children or child attributes. When you're ready to save your data, use the `Add` button, or hit `[Enter]`.

Comment: +1 - The key here is to add a child after you add a parent. The Forge GUI doesn't appear to let you create empty objects.

Comment: Good tip. I had problems with my child name ( Firebase's, I've got no children myself), they cannot contain a dot.

Comment: Cool, the main problem is that apparently you can't create empty objects/lists, you will need to create always a fake object in order to plan your structure

Comment: @Rob DiMarco is there is a way to generate key manually we adding child?

Comment: @Tefa I don't follow your question, can you elaborate? Firebase lets you choose *any* key, or have one generated for you if you prefer.

Answer (score 18):

An interface that would efficiently and quickly edit a hierarchy of data would naturally need to anticipate that hierarchy. So you're not going to find a pre-built tool to edit tiered data without tedious data entry.

Generally, I keep a second browser window opened, logged in with admin privileges, and just manually input the objects using the browser's debugger (e.g. Firebug). I find this quite a bit faster than import/export of JSON (and writing JSON is so tedious!).

Generally, I prefer `update` over `set`, as this means I can just enter the changes rather than having to write out the entire hierarchy:

```
new Firebase(MY_URL).child(PATH).update({
   // replace the widgets
   widgets: {
      one: { color: 'red', shape: 'square' },
      two: { color: 'green', shape: 'triangle' }
   },

   // reset the count
   widgetCount: 0,

   // delete my status
   status: null
});
```

If neither the Forge tools nor inputting via debugger suits you, then you might find it worth the investment to write a quick and dirty, ugly and primitive, admin page where you can alter the data and save it.

I have several of these, which I whipped up in around an hour each, to use for frequent admin routines on our sites. The trick is to build only what you need and not get caught up in how cool and awesome it could be. Spartan FTW.

Answer (score 10):

Using slashes for specifying your subdirectories will allow this. (object/object:)

Answer (score 6):

Clicking on the "+" button allows you to add as many levels as you wish. Simple as that.

[image]