# Simulate Firebase push() in Graphical UI (Forge)

Tags: firebase

I'm able to enter multi-level data in my app and in the Graphical UI, i.e. Forge, ([Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696495/manually-inserting-data-in-firebase)), but I want to simulate the [push()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html) functionality to generate a unique child name.

I tried leaving the parent name blank, and creating list items under it (filling in all names and values), but nothing gets saved.

Is there something else to enter in the parent name, so a unique value is created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no push() command in Forge. There's really no need for it as it's slow to enter the data key-by-key and you'd manage it faster by just opening the JavaScript console and punching it in.

Since Forge is already authenticated as an admin, you can open your debugger from there, and type something like this:

```
new Firebase(URL+'/path/to/data').push({ ... values ... });
```

Alternately, if you're determined to enter them in the UI, you can obtain a push id by the same means:

```
new Firebase(URL+'/path/to/data').push().name();
```

Then copy/paste that into the browser.

Comment: I tried the Console after logging into Firebase.com and received an 'Unexpected token' error when trying your first suggestion.

Comment: I do have a need for testing and learning purposes, so I only plan on entering a few records.

Comment: An Unexpected token indicates that your js code did not parse. You'll need to actually enter valid data. `... values...` is intended to be replaced by your key/value pairs and needs to be valid javascript. Also, `URL` represents your Firebase URL. If you're only entering a few records for learning purposes, just assign them ids like `rec1` and `rec2`. Why do they need to be generated by Firebase?

Comment: Fixed the js error and then made sure I was on the Data page. It helps when things are consistent. The firebase documentation considers using push() to be "The Better Way". Replicating that functionality in the GUI would be less confusing by being consistent. Otherwise, leaving the parent name blank just doesn't add anything. Why do I need that?